# which data structure to use for giving unique riddles to users?

Tags: database-design, data-structures

So I am making a website where a group of users try to answer riddles at the same time and later are able to submit riddles to the website.

I want to make it so that a user is never given the same riddle twice. So I wanted advice on how to create a User.js class and a Group.js class

User.js class needs a data structure to represent riddles it's never seen. Let's call it RiddlesNotSeenByUser for now.

The Group.js class needs to be able to merge all the RiddlesNotSeenByUser for each user into a data structure let's call RiddlesNotSeenByGroup.

Then I am going to have a huge database of riddles and I am going to need to efficiently
find a riddle in the database not in the data structure RiddlesNotSeenByGroup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to keep a RiddlesNotSeen list, because if you do then every time a new user is added you have to populate his list with all the existing riddles. And whenever a new riddle is added you have to update every user. If the number of users and the number of riddles are even moderately large, you're going to find this incredibly expensive.

You're better off keeping a RiddlesSeen list, and updating it every time the user sees a new riddle. Then, when you want to select a new riddle for the user to see, you get the entire list of riddles, remove those that he's seen, and randomly select from the result. Databases are very good at doing that.